# matlab linear equations with mod

Tags: matlab, modulus, equations

I have a simple equations to solve and I want to do it in matlab,however, there are some years, that I didn't use and kinda forgot it.
So this

> > linsolve({(387=mod(324*a+b,601)), (491=mod(381*a+b,601))},{a,b}),

doesn't give me a result, due to an a mistake I am not able to find.
the original set of equations is:

(324a+b)mod601=387
(381a+b)mod601=491,

affine cipher apparently.
Thank you!

Comment: If mod is a reminder after division, those are not linear equations, so linsolve cannot be applied.

Comment: could you please tell me a function that I shoul use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
First make you function  describing equations in a separate file with the name myfunc.m:

```
function y=myfunc(x)
    y(1)=mod(324*x(1)+x(2),601)-387;
    y(2)=mod(381*x(1)+x(2),601)-491;
```

than apply `fsolve` like

```
x0=[1; 1];
[ans,err]=fsolve(@myfunc,x0)
```

`x0` is a guess to the solution. This method gives an approximate numerical solution around your guess.

`fsolve` solves a system of nonlinear equations. It has many parameters, you can read about them in MATLAB help.

Let me know if it works

Comment: sorry i have made a mistake, y1 and y2 should be replaced by y(1) and y(2). I have corrected the function

Comment: thank you again! the equation solved, however, I got strange numbers, but it is an another story!

Comment: check equations one more time and play with the guess x0. At the beginning I have messed up with signs in the equations. I have got these numbers for your example: 1.8246, -204.1579 with maximal absolute error 0.0147

Comment: yes, I've got the same numbers. I suspect there can be a mistake in formulation but with every change I will use your base, so it is ok!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with these equations,

```
(324*a + b) mod 601 = 387,
(381*a + b) mod 601 = 491,
```

we can conclude that

```
((381*a + b) - (324*a + b)) mod 601 = (491 - 387) mod 601
```

and therefore (performing the obvious simplifications inside the parentheses 
on the left-hand side and fully evaluating the right-hand side),

```
(57*a) mod 601 = 104.
```

That looks a lot easier to solve than the system of two equations in two variables.
Once you know `a`, you can return to one of the original equations and solve for `b`.